# Jest test case stack trace pointing to the wrong line number in the Vue3 project

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component, babeljs, babel-jest

After upgraded the Vue framework version 2 to 3 I faced an issue with the jest test case where the stack trace line number was showing as wrong and it affects the **sonarqube coverage report** for vue extension files. Can someone help me to fix this issue ?

transform for vue extention file ; **vue/vue3-jest**

**Babel version = 7.0.0**

babel.config.js

```
    module.exports = {
    presets:
      [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        {
          targets: {
            browsers: ["> 1%", "last 2 versions", "not dead"],
          },
          useBuiltIns: "usage",
          corejs: 3
        },
      ]
    }
```